# Почему при установке приложения создается ярлык на каждый activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Пишу программу в Android Studio, столкнулся с проблемой: при установке своего приложения создается ярлык на приложение  и на 2 activity.

Как исправить?

Вот кусок манифеста:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_2"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.byalynitskiy.autohelper.Activity1" />

      <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_2"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.byalynitskiy.autohelper.Activity1" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: приведите код манифеста

Answer (score 1):

У вас Activity внутри другой Activity, в этом как мне кажется и заключается ошибка. Закройте первую, прежде чем описывать вторую.

Comment: Я бы даже сказал что у него одна и та же активити сама в себе

Answer (score 1):

У вас одинаковые активности. Удалите первую

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?